# API page return Header 500 but Work

Tags: plugins, api, json

I have create a simple API virtual page:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9870_init_external' );    
function wpse9870_init_external()    
{    
    global $wp_rewrite;    
    $plugin_url = plugins_url( 'api.php', __FILE__ );    
    $plugin_url = substr( $plugin_url, strlen( home_url() ) + 1 );          
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'api.php$', $plugin_url );    
}    
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9870_init_internal' );
function wpse9870_init_internal()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'api.php$', 'index.php?wpse9870_api=1', 'top' );
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse9870_query_vars' );
function wpse9870_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse9870_api';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'wpse9870_api', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        include 'api.php';
        exit();
    }
    return;
}
```

Now the code:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "index.php?wpse9870_api=1"))    
{
   header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
   echo "v1p"; 
}
```

The page work and return "v1p" in simple test but header is 500 and if make a post with :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/index.php?wpse9870_api=1',
```

it return error on:

error: function(response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)); });

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"v1p﻿","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Can you help me? Before changing server all work, now i have LAMP with Apache 2.4.27 and before cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I have solver with

```
die;
```

After echo.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "index.php?wpse9870_api=1"))    
{
   header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
   echo "v1p"; 
   die;
}
```

Header is now 200;